# setTimeout runs indefinetly inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, use-effect

I am trying to make a notification toast component. And I want it to be removed after 2 seconds (not-shown on the screed) Although, it is removed (not-shown on the screen via top:-100 argument), the component is getting rendered infinitely. You can see it from the console.log's I have placed inside the component and inside the `useEffect` call with `setTimeout`.

My expectation is that `setTimeout` should run `setShowState` after 2 seconds and then `useEffect` should do the cleanup and remove the timer. So everything is back to normal until `showState` changes.

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import I18n from '../../i18n'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {createGlobalStyle} from 'styled-components'
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'

const NotificationStyle = createGlobalStyle`
    @media (max-width: 500px) {
        .notification_mssg {
            left: 10px;
        }
    }
`

const Container = styled.div`
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: ${(props) => props.top}px;
  right: 16px;
  z-index: 2000;
  transition: top 0.5s ease;
`

const NoticitactionIcon = styled.div`
  float: left;
  font-size: 27px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
`

const NotificationMessage = styled.span`
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
`

function NotificationAlertRoot(props) {

  const create_notification = useSelector((state) => state.notifications.create_notification)

  const {message, code} = create_notification.success_info
  const [showState, setShowState] = useState({top: -100, msg: message, bgColor: '#444'})

  // show notification
  useEffect(() => {
    setShowState({top: 96, msg: I18n.t(message), bgColor: backgroundColor(code)})
  }, [message, code])

  console.log('amIrendered', showState) // although showState doesn't change, component is getting rendered infinitely :/

  // hide notification after 2 seconds
  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      setShowState({
        top: -100,
        msg: '',
        bgColor: `#ffffff00`,
      })
      console.log("timerId", timerId) // I see timerId is changing so the problem most probably in this useEffect call.
    }, 2000)

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timerId)
    }
  }, [showState])

  const notificationIcon = (bgColor) => {
    switch (bgColor) {
      case '#32c786':
        return (
          <NoticitactionIcon style={{background: '#2aa872'}}>
            <i className="zmdi zmdi-info" />
          </NoticitactionIcon>
        )
      case '#ffc721':
        return (
          <NoticitactionIcon style={{background: '#fabb00'}}>
            <i className="zmdi zmdi-alert-triangle" />
          </NoticitactionIcon>
        )
      case '#ff6b68':
        return (
          <NoticitactionIcon style={{background: '#ff4642'}}>
            <i className="zmdi zmdi-alert-circle" />
          </NoticitactionIcon>
        )
      default:
        return <span></span>
    }
  }

  function backgroundColor(code) {
    switch (Math.floor(code / 100)) {
      case 2:
        return '#32c786'
      case 3:
        return '#ffc721'
      case 4:
        return '#ff6b68'
      case 5:
        return '#ff6b68'
      default:
        return '#444'
    }
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <NotificationStyle />
      <Container
        className="notification_mssg"
        top={showState.top}
        style={{background: showState.bgColor}}
      >
        {notificationIcon(showState.bgColor)}
        <NotificationMessage>{showState.msg}</NotificationMessage>
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default NotificationAlertRoot
```

Do you have an idea what is wrong above?

Comment: try  set '-100px'

Comment: @Robert That shouldn't matter as he applies the px in the styled comp.

Comment: and it know that is px not em, rem, ch ?

Comment: I think its because you are updating the showState in useEffect so after two seconds when it clears it will fire again because it notices a change.

Comment: there is not a problem notification disappearance. It disaappears nicely after 2 seconds but component is getting rendered indefinetly. timerId gets a new timerId every 2 second as you can see from the console.log

Comment: May I ask why you are including `showState` in the second `useEffect` dependency? Have you tried passing an empty dependency array? As you are not using the `showState` value inside the second `useEffect` I'm not sure why you included it.

Comment: if I don't include it notification doesn't disappear. So it should follow showState to do its job. When showState changes through useSelector it should appear then the second useEffect should clear it after 2 seconds with setTimeOut.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem comes from your dependency array. Your `useEffect` is dependent on `showState` and each time, you are calling `setShowState` in your `useEffect` when `setShowState` is called `showState` changes and then again, your `useEffect`
gets invoked(it is dependent on `ShowState`), and again `setShowState` is called and ...
infinity loop!

Comment: first useEffect sets the showState with `setShowState` and then follows the message and code coming from the redux store that is fine. second useEffect follows `showState` to do its job (removing it after two seconds) so I have to follow it on the second useEffect. and when I also console.log showState inside the second useEffect I see showState is not changing at all too.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root of the problem. Sometimes you are too focused on something and you forget the little details of useEffect. It is always dangerous to provide objects as dependency arrays to useEffect. The dependency array values should be simple values. So now I introduced a new state (flag, setFlag) with just boolean values and I make the second useEffect just to follow that simple value.  Everything is working just fine now.

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import I18n from '../../i18n'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {createGlobalStyle} from 'styled-components'
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'

const NotificationStyle = createGlobalStyle`
    @media (max-width: 500px) {
        .notification_mssg {
            left: 10px;
        }
    }
`

const Container = styled.div`
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: ${(props) => props.top}px;
  right: 16px;
  z-index: 2000;
  transition: top 0.5s ease;
`

const NotificationIcon = styled.div`
  float: left;
  font-size: 27px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
`

const NotificationMessage = styled.span`
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
`

function NotificationAlertRoot(props) {

  const create_notification = useSelector((state) => state.notifications.create_notification)

  const {message, code} = create_notification.success_info
  const [showState, setShowState] = useState({top: -100, msg: message, bgColor: '#444'})
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false) // when you follow the showState at the second useEffect you have an infinite loop. Because it is an object.

  // show notification
  useEffect(() => {
    setShowState({top: 96, msg: I18n.t(message), bgColor: backgroundColor(code)})
    setFlag(true)
  }, [message, code])

  // hide notification after 2 seconds
  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      setShowState({top: -100,msg: '', bgColor: `#ffffff00`})
      setFlag(false)
    }, 2000)

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timerId)
    }
  }, [flag]) // showState

  const notificationIcon = (bgColor) => {
    switch (bgColor) {
      case '#32c786':
        return (
          <NotificationIcon style={{background: '#2aa872'}}>
            <i className="zmdi zmdi-info" />
          </NotificationIcon>
        )
      case '#ffc721':
        return (
          <NotificationIcon style={{background: '#fabb00'}}>
            <i className="zmdi zmdi-alert-triangle" />
          </NotificationIcon>
        )
      case '#ff6b68':
        return (
          <NotificationIcon style={{background: '#ff4642'}}>
            <i className="zmdi zmdi-alert-circle" />
          </NotificationIcon>
        )
      default:
        return <span></span>
    }
  }

  const backgroundColor = (code) => {
    switch (Math.floor(code / 100)) {
      case 2:
        return '#32c786'
      case 3:
        return '#ffc721'
      case 4:
        return '#ff6b68'
      case 5:
        return '#ff6b68'
      default:
        return '#444'
    }
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <NotificationStyle />
      <Container
        className="notification_mssg"
        top={showState.top}
        style={{background: showState.bgColor}}
      >
        {notificationIcon(showState.bgColor)}
        <NotificationMessage>{showState.msg}</NotificationMessage>
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default NotificationAlertRoot
```

Comment: I would suggest to use JSON.stringify(showState) as a dependency. This way you don't use an object as a dependency and don't need the flag.